# Something making NServiceBus lose messages

Tags: iis, iis-7, nservicebus

I have an NServiceBus configuration that is working great on developers machines and in my Development Environment.

However, when I move it to my Test Environment my messages just start getting tossed.

Here is the system:

1. An app gets a TCP message from a Mainframe system and sends it to a MSMQ (call it `FromMainframe`).
2. An application hosted in IIS has a "Handle" method for that MSMQ and processes the messages from the mainframe.

In my Test Environment, step two only half way happens.  The message is popped off the MSMQ, but not processed by my application.

Effectively my data is **LOST**!  NServiceBus removes them from the Queue but I never get to process them.  They are not even in the error queue!

**These are the things I have tried** in an attempt to figure out what is happening:

1. Check the Config files
2. Attach a remote debugger to the process to see what the `Handle` method is doing

   - The `Handle` method is never called (but when I attach to the Development Environment my breakpoint in my `Handle` method is hit and it all works flawlessly).
3. Redeploy my Dev version to the Test Envioronment and try step 2 again (just in case the versions were not exactly the same.)
4. Check the Config files again
5. Check that the Error queue is not filling up

   - The error queue stays empty (I wish it would fill up, then my data would not be LOST).
6. Check for any other process that may be pulling stuff from my MSMQs

   - I Turned off my IIS website and the messages in the `FromMainframe` queue start to backup.
   - When I turn it back on, the messages disappear fairly fast (but still not all at once).  The speed that they disappear is too fast for them to be processed by my `Handle` method.
7. Check Config files yet again.
8. Run the NServiceBusTools\MsmqUtils\Runner.exe \i

   - I ran it, rebooted, ran it again and again for good measure!
9. Check the Configs again (I must have missed SOMETHING right?)
10. Check the Development Environment Configs are not pointing to the Test Environment

    - I don't think it is possible to use another computer's MSMQ as your input queue, but it does not hurt to check.
11. Look for any catch blocks that could be silently killing my message.
12. One last check of the Config files.
13. Recreate my Test Environment on another machine (it worked flawlessly)
14. Run my stuff outside of IIS.

    - When I host outside of IIS (using NServiceBus.Host.exe) it all works fine.  So it has to be an IIS thing right?
15. Go **crazy** and hope that stack overflow can offer any kind of insight.

Comment: Is NSB being hosting inside of IIS?  What protocols is it configured for?  Is your queue transactional?  Is MSDTC up and running?  Does the App Pool identity have the correct permissions on the queue?  Do the messages end up in the system dead letter queue?

Comment: Did you configure log4net to capture all nservicebus output? Your answer might be in there.. Also which version of nservicebus?

Comment: @AdamFyles - NSB is being hosted in IIS.  I will need to check the protocols (I did not think that would affect NSB).  My MSMQ was setup by NSB.  So I would suppose that it is transactional.  The App pool does have the correct permissions.  An the messages do not end up in the dead letter queue.  (They are just gone)

Comment: @Sarmaad - I have not done that.  Nor do I know how to.  If you know how please post it.  (If not I will dig it up.)  I am running NSB 2.6.0.1506

Comment: Can you read off the queue from code outside IIS?  You can also try turning on negative source journaling in MSMQ.  This help you identify what is happening to the messages.

Comment: @AdamFyles - I don't think Negative Source Journaling will help.  I can see the queue filling up.  The messages get in there just fine.  It is when the application goes to process them that the problem happens.  Handle never gets called.  It is as if NServiceBus has something telling it to consider the message "processed" before it ever calls "Handle".  (Maybe I don't understand Negative Source Journaling, but I thought it was for issues where the message does not ever arrive.)

Comment: I was wondering if that might catch why they don't end up in the error queue.  I'm stumped as to why NSB doesn't show you any kind of error, which is why I'm leaning towards something is wrong in the infrastructure.  Can you post how your endpoint is configured?

Comment: @AdamFyles - I don't know how to turn on negative source journaling right on the queue.  I only see an option for normal Journaling.  Do you know how to turn it on?

Comment: @AdamFyles - I tried setting up my MSMQ to run outside of IIS (using NServiceBus.Host.exe)  It worked great!  I think this means it has to be an IIS thing.  So I have added IIS to the tags.

Comment: @AdamFyles - I checked the protocols.  They are: http, net.tcp, net.pipe, net.msmq, msmq.formatname.

Comment: I would try turning of the msmq based protocols or shutting down the related listener services in case WAS is "stealing" your messages.  Here's a good link on missing messages: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/01/22/why-does-msmq-keep-losing-my-messages.aspx

Comment: @AdamFyles - Thank you for your help on this.  I think I got an answer as to what happened.  (See below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I know enough about what happened to throw out an "Answer".

When I setup my NServiceBus self hosting I had a call that loaded the message handlers.

```
NServiceBus.Configure.With().LoadMessageHandlers()
```

(There are more configurations, but I omitted them for brevity)

When you call this, NServiceBus scans the assmeblies for a class that implements `IHandleMessages<T>`.

So, somehow, on my Test Environment Machine, the ServiceBus scan of the directory for a class that calls IHandleMessages was failing to find my class (even though the assembly was absolutely there).

Turns out that if NServiceBus does not find something that handles a message it will **THROW IT AWAY**!!!

This is a total **design bug** in my opinion.  The whole idea of NServiceBus is to not lose your data, but in this case it does just that!

Now, once you know about this pitfall, there are several ways around it.

1. Expressly state what your handler(s) should be:

   `NServiceBus.Configure.With().LoadMessageHandlers<First<MyMessageType>>()`
2. Even further protection is to add another handler that will handle "Everything else".  `IMessage` is the base for all message payloads, so if you put a handler on it, it will pickup everything.
   If you set IMessage to [handle after](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/handlers/handler-ordering) your messages get handled, then it will handle everything that NServiceBus can't find a handler for.  If you throw and exception in that `Handle` method that will cause NServiceBus to to move the message to the `error` queue.  (What I think should be the **default** behavior.)

Comment: Was your work around to state all your message handlers there or just one in the message handling assembly?

Comment: @Galen - I have only one message handler.  And I explicitly state what it is in my config now.