# How to setup NServiceBus and Log4Net to save to a file (without profiles)

Tags: log4net, nservicebus

I am running NServiceBus and having this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778954/something-making-nservicebus-lose-messages).  To try and troubleshoot it I would like to make NServiceBus log to a file.

The problem is that I am hosting NServiceBus in IIS, not NServiceBus.Host.exe.  Because of that I don't know a way to turn on the the production profile.

Is there a way to tell NServiceBus to log to a file not using profiles?  (Or a way to set the profile when not using NServiceBus.Host.exe?)

I had hoped that there is a way change `NServiceBus.Configure.With().Log4Net();` to put an `Appender` in that will log to a file.  But I don't see anyway to do that in code (all the examples use xml).

Alternatly if there is a way to change this to log to a file that would be great too:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="Logging" type="NServiceBus.Config.Logging, NServiceBus.Core" />
</configSections>

<Logging Threshold="FINE" />
```

Does anyone know how to do either of these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `IWantCustomLogging`:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/GenericHost/LoggingFromAppConfig/EndpointConfig.cs

And specify the RollingFileAppender in code:

`Configure.Log4net< RollingFileAppender>(...)`